# Can we determine the color of metal from the basic principle of quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, metals

Is there any method by which we determine the color of metal, such as starting from the basic principle of quantum mechanics?

Comment: The short answer would be yes. Metals surfaces are reflective. So they usually reflect almost all radiation that falls on it. Your mirror is coated with metal at the back, so it just reflects all the light and therefore has the colour of whatever frequency of light falls on it. 
It is of course in theory possible to calculate the frequency dependence of reflective of different metals from QM by modelling the electron energy levels of the metal sample.

Comment: @Kolandiolaka - that kind of neglects all the solid state physics (sure, based on QM) buried in determining the optical properties of the metal.